# Responding to ActionResults with jQuery, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I know how to respond to a form post in ASP.NET MVC using jQuery, but I'm having trouble with something that is a little bit more simple.

The scenario is that there is a list of items on the screen, like an ordered list.

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li> // each will corrospond with an id.
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

This is a crude example, of course, but the basic jist is that when the user clicks one, it will perform some server side logic... so in the controller, there is a method such as ..

```
public bool CheckSomething(int id)
{
 // do some logic to determine if the result should be true
 return true;
}
```

It's very simple logic, really - but it still requires database access, so I cannot do it in javascript. I need to have it hit my controller. The problem is that I want the UI to respond to this.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to exactly wire this up without using a Form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jquery ajax. This example should get you going.

**Server:**

```
public JsonResult CheckSomething(int id)
{
 // do some logic to determine if the result should be true
 return Json(true);
}
```

**Client:**

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/[controller name]/checksomething/' + this.id,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result){
            if(result) {} //...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This was my first thought, too - the problem I am running into is that when the Controller returns "true" as a Boolean, it doesn't seem to be accepted that way in javascript. I've noticed you have flagged the dataType as json - how does this corrospond to the way the Controller should return the data?

Comment: @Stacey - you need to use a JsonResult and return Json([object]). See updated post

Comment: Josiah, you're missing the second argument to Json() to allow GET requests (assuming ASP.NET MVC 2+).  Alternatively, you could make sure that the JQuery ajax call uses POST as its method.

Comment: That was the ticket. That makes sense - I forgot that jQuery can deserialize json as well. I was avoiding that because I figured I would have to do a lot of packing and unpacking. This didn't work out of the box, but I've figured it out. Thanks for the help - I'm ashamed I didn't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a key component of MVC, to which I recommend walking through the Nerd Dinner sample application to get a full grasp on the basics of ASP.NET MVC.

Anyways, when you're printing your `Item 1` links, you should be using Html.ActionLink, passing in the ID of the data you want to manipulate, and add the appropriate Action method in your Controller to handle this.

Comment: No, I'm not missing the key component of MVC - I am doing exactly what I intend to do in this specific situation. It needs to respond with Javascript from a non-form post. If a simple hyperlink would work, I would just do that. But that won't work for what needs to happen.

Comment: You will need to implement some AJAX, which MVC was ever-so-graceful in including within the framework.